# Mongoid - How to create a document with embedded documents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am currently working on a Rails project using Mongoid. I have a `Game` model defined, which embeds many `GamePlayers`. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to create new games. I can create a game with no players using `Game.create`, but when I try to create players for the game as well, it gives a syntax error. I've tried searching online, but I haven't been able to find anything that looks relevant to the problem.

Here is my attemped creation code in the `GamesController`.

```
  def new
    @game = Game.create(
        epoch: 1,    
        turn: 0,
        auction_turn: -1,
        auction_type: -1,
        sun: 1,
        ras: 0,
        auction_track: []

        game_players: [ #doesn't work
          { suns:[9,6,5,2]
          }        
        ]      
    )

    redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @game._id
  end
```

Which produces the error

```
/home/<redacted>/Ra/ra_server/app/controllers/games_controller.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
        game_players: [ #doesn't work
```

Here are my models

```
class Game
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :epoch, type:Integer
  field :turn, type:Integer
  field :auction_turn, type:Integer
  field :auction_type, type:Integer
  field :sun, type:Integer
  field :ras, type:Integer
  field :auction_track, type:Array


  embeds_many :game_players 
end

class GamePlayer
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :score, type:Integer
  field :bid, type:Integer
  field :suns, type:Array
  field :next_suns, type:Array
  field :pharaohs, type:Integer
  field :niles, type:Integer
  field :floods, type:Integer
  field :gods, type:Integer
  field :gold, type:Integer
  field :civilizations, type:Array
  field :monuments, type:Array

  embedded_in :game
end
```

Comment: What about adding a comma after auction_track: []?

Comment: @Rebit Thanks, I can't believe I missed that. Anyway, it appears to be working now.

Comment: Sure thing! I just wrote it up as an official answer so people will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are missing a comma after auction_track: [] in your parameters.